# Google Sheets // Is it possible to use a cell for value Input, but also as Output from a different input?

Tags: google-sheets, cell

[image: Spreadsheet]

So what I'm trying to accomplish here is having column (B) as Input.

**Ascension:** B5= Input, then it sums C5=B5/1000 for volume conversion.
**Ullage in m3's.:** `D3=B3/C5`
**Ullage in mm's:** `D4=B4*C5`

Row 2 and 5 are irrelevant for the request.

My question is: Can I Input a value in B3 so that Divides by C5 and shows in D3 like now, BUT, also updates D4 and therefor automatically B4.

Let's say my input in (B3) is 100 divided by 2 (C5) = (D3)50. Now I would like for (D4) to take over that 100 from (B3) and  also divide that by 2 to show in (B4). BUT, now when I input a value into (B4), I want it to multiply by (C5) and do the same trick with D3 and B3.

Basically, a cross-working calculator based on what input value I have that updates the other to not get confused reading the data.

Might be too complex, but thought I'd give it a shot here. Thanks.

Google, Stackoverflow.com, Youtube, Messing around myself..

Comment: you can have only two states within a cell. its either formula or manual input.

Comment: With formulas it's not possible, you would have a circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I worried as much.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort it out with hidden columns, and values that expand to the next column in which you'd like to have your result or input your value.
Instead a formula: `=B3/B4` you'd have `={",",B3/B4}`

So, if you manually insert a value in the right column, the formula in left column won't expand. As an example I've created a very dummy calculator of sides and hypothenuse. In B1 (column B in red would be hidden) I have:

```
={"","Res: "&(C3^2-C2^2)^(1/2)}
```

And so on in the next rows. In this picture I've inserted manual values in C1 and C2, so C3 has a result:

[[image]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXdTl.jpg)

And another example in another row:

[image]

You can test it out here and the extrapolate it to your formulas,
(I've erased the part with "Res. " so the result is an actual number, it was just for easier view in my examples):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZaEEGWtLU-LXBmg-xy80Ps_biuYhb8WxZBs0g1tGE00/edit?usp=drivesdk