# Google sheets Script include formula when adding new rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, array-formulas

I want to include a script on my sheet to include N/A with a formula to certain cells (Example: I6:K6 & N6) but only to include this if C6 contains "A or B" if C6 contains "C" then not to include the formula.

I wouldn't be able to use an array formula within a cell as the value where N/A would go may need to be manually overridden.

I have tried a few different ways and I can only get it to work to check if the current cell you are in contains the text and it will trigger to apply N/A in the other cells. However it will only do the N/A if you are still on the active cell, if you move off that cell it will stop the trigger.

`````
    if (values[i][0].match("A") != null) {
        var nextCell = iis.offset(0, 6);
        if (nextCell.getValue() === '');
        nextCell.setValue("N/A");
    }
}````

I have also tried another way but it will override all of the existing data I already have within my sheet which is not what I want. 

````var lastRow = ii.getLastRow();

ii.getRange("I3").setFormula("=IF(REGEXMATCH(C3,\"A|B\"),\"N/A\",\"\")");
var fillDownRange = ii.getRange(3, 9, (lastRow - 1));
ii.getRange("I3").copyTo(fillDownRange);````
`````

Answer (score 0):

You could try an approach like I exposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102092/google-sheets-is-it-possible-to-use-a-cell-for-value-input-but-also-as-outpu/75104799#75104799), if you're able to add a couple of hidden columns (one before your current I and K, and other before N). This way you'll be able to use an ARRAYFORMULA they will expand to adjacent cells when you specify it. Let me know!